# Apparent missing link to the original question

Tags: support, bug

[Article when there is an adjective before a noun](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25428/article-when-there-is-an-adjective-before-a-noun)
There is a banner saying that this question is already asked some other place but link to that other place is absent.

Comment: The original link provided  is: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152/when-should-i-use-a-vs-an

Answer (score 4):

The link is there, but it is not in the banner, it is just below it.

The way duplicate close banners are displayed was updated a while ago, I'm not sure when exactly, but after this question was closed. All duplicate banners should have been updated accordingly.

This question, however, had its duplicate banner edited (http to https in the link) before the update and I assume that this little change somehow tripped up the algorithm that changed all the banners.

I will reopen and close the question, and that should fix the issue.